# How can I send an stripe invoice on my website to any body?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, invoice

everyone,
I have been developing own my website to handle the invoice system.

but I face a problem now, I wanted a user(A) who signed up my website can send an invoice to any user(B), I assume that user A has already signed up stripe, but I wanted him/her to sign up stripe in my website or maybe not.

then, how can send an invoice and get paid on my site. I don't know his/her stripe API key. I don't need any fees from them.
If I know the stripe API key of A, I think Its easy and there is no problem.
how can do this on my website without the user's API key? or Is there another solution?

```
A send an invoice to B on my website and then get paid from B.

const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_4eC39HqL...c');

const invoice = await stripe.invoices.create({
  customer: 'cus_...1P',
});
```

Thank you in advance, stripe experts.

Comment: I am not entirely sure about this yet, but you can look at Stripe Connect.

Comment: yes, I am looking at the connected account on the stripe, maybe it will be the solution @Zhi Kai.